# Issues deleting this specific row from Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running this on Databricks, and I am having a hard time dropping a row. By default when uploading a document, all rows have the heading '_c1, _c2, _c3 ...':
[image: My example CSV file]

I want the first row to be my heading, and I am having difficulties doing this.

As for code, this is the furthest that I have gotten (my dataframe is df):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(df.index[0])
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None
```

And this returns a dataframe that looks like this: 
[image]

I think I am on the right track, but I don't know how to delete the row 0 entirely. 'df.drop(df.index[0])' didn't seem to work. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `inplace=True` in the *drop* method:

```
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)
```

Otherwise it returns a new data frame with the first row dropped, and you need to assign it back to `df`:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, the inplace=True was exactly what was needed.

Comment: Just want to point out that in place operations are not idiomatic in pandas. The second of these is preferred.